# Twitter Chill crashing on Android

Tags: android, scala, proguard, kryo

I am trying Kryo+Chill (`com.twitter:chill_2.11:0.8.0` and Scala version is `2.11.8`). Following code works fine on desktop, but on Android it crashes.

```
  case class TestDogRef(id: Int)

  case class TestDog(ref: TestDogRef, name: String, friends: Seq[TestDogRef])

  class TestHouse[T](val data: Seq[T])

  case class TestDogHouse(override val data: Seq[TestDog]) extends TestHouse[TestDog](data)

    def serialize[A](data: A): Array[Byte] = {
      val instantiator = new ScalaKryoInstantiator
      instantiator.setRegistrationRequired(false)
      val kryo = instantiator.newKryo()
      val bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream
      val output = new Output(bao)
      kryo.writeObject(output, data)
      output.close()
      bao.toByteArray
    }

    def deserialize[A](ser: Array[Byte], clazz: Class[A]): A = {
      val instantiator = new ScalaKryoInstantiator
      instantiator.setRegistrationRequired(false)
      val kryo = instantiator.newKryo()
      val input = new Input(new ByteArrayInputStream(ser))
      val deserData = kryo.readObject(input, clazz)
      deserData
    }

  override def run(): String = {
      val orig = TestDogHouse(Seq(TestDog(TestDogRef(4), "Doggy", Seq(TestDogRef(1)))))
      val serialized = serialize(orig)
      val deserialized = deserialize(serialized, classOf[TestDogHouse])
      deserialized.toString
    }
```

Here is the crash:

```
  07-14 11:55:42.053 6744-6764/x.y E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 137
                                                                            java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                                at com.twitter.chill.java.PackageRegistrar.all(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.twitter.chill.AllScalaRegistrar.apply(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.twitter.chill.ScalaKryoInstantiator.newKryo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$KryoWithChillTest$.serialize(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$KryoWithChillTest$.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at x.y.a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.j.onSurfaceChanged(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
                                                                                at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
                                                                             Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Error while getting field 'words' of bitSet
                                                                                at com.twitter.chill.java.BitSetSerializer.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.twitter.chill.java.PackageRegistrar.all(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at com.twitter.chill.AllScalaRegistrar.apply(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at com.twitter.chill.ScalaKryoInstantiator.newKryo(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$KryoWithChillTest$.serialize(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$KryoWithChillTest$.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at x.y.a.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.j.onSurfaceChanged(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505) 
                                                                                at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: words
                                                                                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:631)
                                                                                at com.twitter.chill.java.BitSetSerializer.<clinit>(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at com.twitter.chill.java.PackageRegistrar.all(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at com.twitter.chill.AllScalaRegistrar.apply(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at com.twitter.chill.ScalaKryoInstantiator.newKryo(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$KryoWithChillTest$.serialize(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$KryoWithChillTest$.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at x.y.LibraryTests$.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at x.y.a.a(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.j.onSurfaceChanged(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505) 
                                                                                at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

I suspect it is because of ProGuard - something gets mangled or dropped, but I have no idea what else I can do.

Relevant proguard rules:

```
-keep class scala.collection.BitSet { *; }
-keepclassmembers class scala.collection.BitSet { *; }
-keep class scala.collection.immutable.BitSet { *; }
-keepclassmembers class scala.collection.immutable.BitSet { *; }
-keep class scala.collection.BitSetLike { *; }
-keepclassmembers class scala.collection.BitSetLike { *; }
-keep class scala.collection.immutable.BitSet.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class scala.collection.immutable.BitSet.** { *; }
-keepnames class scala.** { *; }
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is not related to ProGuard. The `chill` java library has a `BitSetSerializer` for `java.util.BitSet` classes that accesses a field (named `words`) via reflection. Now the `java.util.BitSet` implementation that is included in Android (derived from the Apache Harmony project upto Android 6, Android N will be based on OpenJDK) does not have such a field and you will get the runtime error as seen in the question.

Looking at the source code of the chill-scala library, using a `ScalaKryoInstantiator` will also register all Java related serializers. You might be able to circumvent the issue by using an `EmptyScalaKryoInstantiator` instead and registering all the needed serializers:

```
 val instantiator = new EmptyScalaKryoInstantiator
 instantiator.setRegistrationRequired(false)
 val kryo = instantiator.newKryo()

 val col = new ScalaCollectionsRegistrar
 col(kryo)
 ScalaTupleSerialization.register(kryo)
 .... 
 // others as needed
```

See also [ScalaKryoInstantiator.scala](https://github.com/twitter/chill/blob/f5b28caa65d519867cb99c2d5246d8a1cc3e3b43/chill-scala/src/main/scala/com/twitter/chill/ScalaKryoInstantiator.scala) for reference which serializers to include.